# http post request sent from android to ashx in asp.net. cannot receive data

Tags: asp.net, android, http-post, ashx

I am sending data from android to a Generic handler .ashx page in asp.net using http post. But the handler is not able to recieve data. The thing works with httpGet but not with httppost

The android code

```
package com.postApp;
/*
 * HTTP POST and BasicNameValuePair
 * */

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class postAct extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    class login{
        public
        String uname;
        public String pass;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


            login l=new login();


        HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:18089/POC_login/Handler.ashx");      


       l.uname="piyush";
       l.pass="gupta";
              List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", l.uname));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", l.pass));
       try {
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(formEntity);

          HttpResponse response;
          response = client1.execute(request);

         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
         String line;
         String page="";
         line = in.readLine();
         while(line!=null)
         {
             page=page+line;
             line=in.readLine();
         }
         TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
         tv.setText(page);
         in.close();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                    
    }


}
```

The ashx code

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {
        context.Request.ContentType = "text/plain";
       // context.Request.ContentType = "text/html";


        string username=context.Request.QueryString["uname"];
        string password = context.Request.QueryString["pass"];
        context.Response.Write("Hello Piyush");

        NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
        var found = (from p in db.Catergories
                    where p.cat_ID == 1
                    select p.cat_name).SingleOrDefault();

    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Please Help!

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's the return status code? I'd recommend adding some debug statements to the code to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thank for your question, I'm learning how to handle post request in web, Is it worked for you below this code? `context.Request.QueryString["supplier_name"];` I changed to `context.Request.Form["supplier_name"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely due to incorrect handling of the content-type.

On the Android side, you should set the Content-type header, e.g.:

```
request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponse response;
response = client1.execute(request);
```

And then you should not override the content-type on your server, i.e. remove the following from ProcessRequest:

```
context.Request.ContentType = "text/plain";
// context.Request.ContentType = "text/html";
```

If you still have problems, be sure to check and make sure your server is configured to receive POSTs.

Answer (score 0):

when u call ashx use **GET**

not POST